# Coloring the area under curve using java

Tags: java, awt, graph-coloring

Can anyone tell me how to color the area under a curve? I have drawn a curve using Graphics2d, but don't know how to color its area.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

"Under a curve" is a bit vague.

If you can draw a curve, then you can fill a curve. When the curve is filled, the endpoints will be connected to make a closed shape.

You can create a GeneralPath that allows you to draw anything, like a shape that has a curve and contains the bottom part of the view area.

I have provided an example of both.

```
package draw;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.GeneralPath;
import java.awt.geom.QuadCurve2D;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

class MyCanvas extends JComponent {

  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    QuadCurve2D q = new QuadCurve2D.Float();
    q.setCurve(10, 30, 10, 200, 100, 100);

    g2.draw(q);
    g2.fill(q);

    GeneralPath closedCurve = new GeneralPath();   
    QuadCurve2D q2 = new QuadCurve2D.Float(); 
    q2.setCurve(0, 200, 150, 150, 300, 200);   
    closedCurve.moveTo(0, 300);
    closedCurve.lineTo(0, 200);
    closedCurve.append(q2, true);
    closedCurve.lineTo(300, 300);
    closedCurve.closePath();

    g2.draw(closedCurve);
    g2.fill(closedCurve);

  }
}

public class DrawArc {
  public static void main(String[] a) {
    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setBounds(30, 30, 300, 320);
    window.getContentPane().add(new MyCanvas());
    window.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```